# View xml file in Internet Explorer from an asp.net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml

I am new to Asp.net. I have a grid view which contains text fields as well as three buttons. My system is generating the xml file and I want to view that xml file in a separate window. Say for example, my grid view contains 3 rows and there will be 3 xml files where one file will be associated with each row. So what I want is to view the file whenever I click the button in the corresponding row.

Can someone help? I know that I need to use some java script.

Comment: Could you please clarify this a bit? Do you want to link to an xml file? Display the contents of an xml file? Bind the xml to your gridview?

Comment: Please change your question from "Can someone help" since it's not a very good question. *The general answer to it is "yes"*

Comment: you can use the xml control if you want, that will be the easiest approach for you

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. For an easy solution you could write the XML in the Response. 
If you want a new window you could create a temporary XML File and redirect to its URL.

```
//create the XML and put it in the filesystem -- just use google

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SomeNameForThisScript", "window.open('http://UrlToYourXML.xml');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

1. You can stream XML, most morden browsers can render XML. Just need to supply style.
2. Use jQuery plugin like [JQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data), to render XML
3. Process XML on server side to convert it to HTML/Datagrid